# Ant Project containing multiple folders to build

Tags: java, ant, build

I am trying to implement below hierarchy in Ant:

ParentProject

```
build.xml
RuntimeFolder_1
    build.xml
RuntimeFolder_2
    build.xml
RuntimeFolder_n
    build.xml
```

Here, When I build ParentFolder build.xml, it should iterate all child folders and build them. A user can add any number of run time folders.
Also, I should able to build RuntimeFolder_1...RuntimeFolder_n individually.
Does someone know how I can do this?

Comment: Step 1: Stop using ant. Step 2: Start using [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html)

Comment: Can I do it easily with Gradle any example?

Comment: Of course it can be done, the solution depends on how you want it to work. Do you want a single multi-project build which is built and released together and lives in a single source repository (with dependencies between projects)? Or do you want many separate builds which are releasable separately and can live in separate source repositories (also with inter-dependencies) and an "uber" build to execute them all at once?

Comment: Yes, I exactly want the single multi project built which can release together and if required built individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, we can use subant: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html

Below is the example:

Parent build.xml will contain:

```
<macrodef name="iterate">
    <attribute name="target"/>
    <sequential>
        <subant target="@{target}">
            <fileset dir="modules" includes="*/build.xml"/>
        </subant>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
<target name="compile">
    <iterate target="compile"/>
</target>
```

Inside folder build.xml will contain those targets.

Answer (score 1):

I know the OP requested Ant but he has expressed an interest in a Gradle solution which might look like

```
build.gradle
settings.gradle
project1/
    build.gradle
project2/
    build.gradle
project3/
    build.gradle
```

Your `settings.gradle` might look like

```
rootDir.listFiles().each {
    if (new File(it, 'build.gradle').exists()) {
        include ":$it.name"
    }
}
```

You'd then apply the `java` plugin to each subproject. This could be done programmatically in the root `build.gradle`

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}
```

Or in each of the `subproject\build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

For further reading see [multi project builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) and the [java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html)